# Swift Show UIbutton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm new in swift and programming. I have a `UIPickerView` and `UIbutton`(by default button is invisible ) in my `storyBoard` and i want to show `myButton` when I change row in a `UIPickerView` (`PickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0) == 1`) and when press `MyButton` do something. Here is my code: `MyButton` and `PickerView`.

How can i show `myButton`?

```
@IBAction func myButton(sender: UIButton) {
        println("Button was clicked", sender)
        //here i will do something

    }


func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
            if  PIckerView.selectedRowInComponent(0) == 1 {
            //how to set UIButton property visible, here ???

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myButton.hidden = false
```

Comment: myButton.hidden = false -- not work, myButton(what i must type here??)

Comment: /Users/bdaler/Documents/Coding/apple/tarjuma/tarjuma/ViewController.swift:254:18: '(UIButton) -> ()' does not have a member named 'hidden'

Comment: You need: @IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton! first

Comment: if i connect myButton as IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton! but how can i do something like this? " @IBAction func myButton(sender: UIButton) {
        println("Button was clicked", sender)
        //here i will do something

    }"

Answer (score 0):

To get access to your button in code you need to create an `IBOutlet`: In InterfaceBuilder ctrl-drag from the button to your class file and in the popup menu choose outlet. Give that outlet a descriptive name i.e. `myButton`. Also give your @IBAction a descriptive name, not `myButton`

So your class will look similar like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func myButtonClick(sender: UIButton) {
    println("Button was clicked", sender)
    // here i will do something
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if  PIckerView.selectedRowInComponent(0) == 1 {
        myButton.hidden = false
    }
}
```

And don't forget to assign your custom class in InterfaceBuilder accordingly.

Comment: and it will be one button?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean?

Comment: thanx. but when selectedRowInComponent equal 1, app crashed: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. (

Comment: Please update your question to include more code of your class, especially the class header. How did you create the `@IBOutlet` and the `@IBAction`? Is your custom class set as the class for your viewController in the identy inspector in InterfaceBuilder?

Comment: Your code looks good. I would suggest to delete the `@IBOutlet` and the `@IBAction` and recreate the connections in InterfaceBuilder.